# Why do we need more powerful computers nowadays?

Tags: computer-engineering

In 1969, NASA was able to conduct its moon mission using a computer with 4KB of RAM.

So, why do we need more powerful computers with more RAMs nowadays?

Comment: One reason is easier to understand code by humans makes code that is less efficient for the machine. And graphics.

Comment: The machines have to be more powerful to compensate for the average intelligence of the user. My first task on a computer was to write a program in Basic to calculate the area of a triangle. How many computer users who live in facebook or Word can do that now?

Comment: @SolarMike: With much tongue in cheek, what's Basic? ;-) As much as I like the way computers & computing have progressed over the years, sometimes I wish Basic still existed so I could write a small test program to quickly check some things out without having to resort to a structured programming language such as Python.

Comment: Think this way - without the supercomputing power, how long it will take a robot to process and respond to a command? NASA had no such worries at that time.

Comment: @Fred so have you considered an emulator to run Basic?

Comment: @Fred - Basic does still exist. FreeBasic can run on Windows, Linux, and Mac.

Comment: Because people write software they don't understand.  Standing on the shoulders of giants gets you reach goals higher and faster, but their use cases were not yours and this results in inefficiency.  throw in extra safety checks to make things usable in place of cryptic user manuals, and you are doing a lot of useless computation.  Finally add in the demand for fancy visuals, refresh rates, and other mostly useless drivel to help obfuscate things important to decision making and you reach the modern age: where people believe it is more efficient for society to have computers guess at answers.

Comment: Because 500 years ago people "were able" to travel hundreds of miles you claim that we had no need to develop railroads or cars or airplanes?

Answer (score 2):

> In 1969, NASA was able to conduct its moon mission using a computer with 4KB of RAM.

**False**.

That may be true for one of the on-board computers. The main mission computers were on the ground due to weight constraints.

Those computers were dedicated to one task and the programs were very carefully crafted. There was a simple 7-segment LED display and keyboard entry. The modern analogy would be a simple micro-controller. The first PIC micro-controller I used had 512 bytes of internal RAM and was able to do useful stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Some 20 to 30 years ago I used to run number crunching models that evaluated the economics of engineering designs. What used to take days of non stop calculating time to complete on a Pentium computer using MS DOS now take hours. The work that used to be able to be done in a week can now be done in one day, if not sooner, because of more powerful computers.

During periods of heavy work loads I used spend a significant part of some Fridays setting up the models to start running prior to leaving for the day so the computers would do the calculations over the weekend. I'd usually drop in to the office over the weekend to ensure everything was running as it should. If not I'd do whatever adjustments were needed and restart the affected models/computers.

It's much better to have results sooner than later.

More powerful computers also allows us to consider more engineering design options and to evaluate the financials  of each option. It allows a degree of optimization that was not possible years ago with lesser computers.

Another way of looking at it is, for your next long distance driving holiday would you prefer to travel in a modern SUV with air conditioning, heating, enclosed cabin, modern suspension system, with a GPS, listening to whatever you want on the sound system, or would you prefer to travel in a [Model T Ford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_Model_T) from 1909, with its open cabin, no air conditioner, no sound system and slower top speed compared to a modern SUV?

They are both cars, but one is much older and one is newer. You decide. By the way, you still only get 2 weeks holiday with either option.

Comment: I will never not be impressed how you guys were able to fend of dinosaurs for days while the calculations were performed.

Comment: @DKNguyen: Dinosaurs were relatively easy to deal with. It was the occasional sub-Neanderthal senior manager who could be difficult!

Comment: @DKNguyen: I just remembered a story that a previous work colleague told me of his time in Sudan in the mid 1980s where his elderly British boss demanded all engineering calculations be done manually using seven figure logarithmic tables - sub Neanderthal senior manager. Unlike dinosaurs that evolved to become birds (with some intelligence), most sub Neanderthal senior managers are becoming extinct. I just hope the UN won't afford them "protect status" as an endangered species.

Comment: I used a sneakernet to upload monthly punchcard records on 200,000 vehicles over covering a 10 year period so I could demonstrate what database programs like DBase II and Focus could do. Got the support center to get the cards onto tape, then broken up unto 7.25 floppies. Then we took over 20 desktops on Friday night, rewired the office phone system, and connected them to a PDP11 I had found in Utah. I had to drive a truck from Georgia to Utah to grab the computer and drums. On Monday, we had to put the phone system back together. This went on for months.

Comment: @PhilSweet: That sounds overly convoluted. What era was that? Punched cards & a PDP11 remind me of my high school days in the 1970s & dBase II reminds me of the late 1980s & early 1990s.

Comment: I had $700 into it when it was done. Yes, it was a PITA, but getting the Honeywell in the support center to talk to the PDP11 was outside the budget. Like tens times outside the budget. This was in the early '80s.

Comment: erm mid '80s 1986 I think

Answer (score 1):

Because we have increased our expectations and demand more intelligent functionality from our computers.

I had an early DOS system on a computer that had just a bios and a floppy drive.

You had the RAM reside on the floppy and you had very primitive word processing or novelty dot drawing snail speed software.

You had to write autoexe. bat commands to load up the program (only one, no multi tasking) and  unload them to clean the RAM for next program.

Now my garden variety pc has 16 GB of RAM, 8 processors, one TB HHD.

It can edit my home movies on the run while I watch a movie and can do a zillion other things in the background.

Many programs in engineering, simulation, design, robotics are getting so intelligent and powerful that have alarmed the society.

In medicine, robots do surgery and intelligent programs design drugs.

We are crossing the gateway of AI, relegating consciousness to machines.

Comment: Then the consequences, read Dune anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Well, for some types of problems, we don't. I worked with some of the Autonetics legacy machines as late as 1994. Designed in the mid '50s, these things could not be beaten by the best GP RISC machines of the 90s applied to the specific tasks the '50s machines were designed for. These were pre-chip machines that later had some 4-bit register chips dead-bugged in.

In the case of the old navigation algorithms, they were not-so-simple comparators. The ground equipment produced a velocity profile of the optimal telemetry. This was uploaded to the flight computer. The flight computer compared the flight instrument data to the stored file and computed steering signals. But this involved some very precise and specialized algorithms and hardware.
The way these old machines were designed pretty much answers the question—

They were essentially complex electromechanical devices. Fixed head disc drives with as many as 16 tracks and upwards of 50 heads controlled the cpu. The outer track was often the clock signal.

Six or eight guys sat around a table and solved the problem at hand, designing the algorithm and hardware simultaneously—soldering up and testing ideas all at the same time. Typical production was five lines of code per day. There were multiple instruction sets for a general purpose machine. The number of microcode instructions was typically in the hundreds. Because of the fixed heads and non-addressable memory, every calculation had to be timed so the result appeared when there was a write head over the desired area of disc. Addressable plated wire memory and core memory existed, but the cost was measured in dollars per bit, and it was heavy, bulky, limited in supply and not reliable for flight. And Autonetics and other guidance producers already had more than 50% of the world's supply of it being used for related ground equipment.

The reason these things work so well is that they did a relatively few things very, very well. Like converting a 3x3 matrix into a triangular matrix. That was done with hardware—we had an instruction for that. Just crank the disk a few turns and you had your triangular matrix. In this sort of environment, it can take a page of flowchart to unpack one instruction. So steering commands could be updated a few times per second, but very accurately. For black box inertial navigation, errors grow nonlinearly, and accuracy is the key.

But these results are highly dependent on the type of application. In the ballistic navigation environment, precision is king and the mathematical problem environment is stable and smooth. Optimization problems in this environment have closed or nearly closed solutions that were found by hand and then implemented digitally. The problem space was fully understood, the algorithm just had to steer a pre-calculated course through it.

Most interesting problems just aren't so well behaved, and you have to explore the problem space as well as navigate through it. That can be done productively using raw speed, a lot less accuracy, and a bit of feedback. And we just don't like spending a couple centuries solving a differential closed form solution to a problem when FEA does the job well enough most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Hypothetically we don't.
HOWEVER NASA communication relayed all telemetry for navigation.
Also the computers, software and people largely capable of running such hardware no one is largely skilled or trained to use.....
In fairness you could easily use primitive computers.